# CSS contrast filter

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, filter, pixel

How does css filter contrast will work ? Is there a formula? I want to reproduce in javascript and I need a formula.
For example css filter brightness(2) take each pixel and multiply by 2, but for contrast I don't have any idea
Thanks

Comment: Nowadays, you can dierectly use CSS filters on canvas context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 2 is a contrast filter. All multiplication and division of an images RGB values affects the contrast.

The function I like to use is a exponential ease function where the power controls the contrast.

```
function contrastPixel(r,g,b,power) {
    r /= 255;  // normalize channels
    g /= 255;
    b /= 255;
    var rr = Math.pow(r,power);  // raise each to the power
    var gg = Math.pow(r,power);
    var bb = Math.pow(r,power);
    r = Math.floor((rr / (rr + Math.pow(1 - r, power)))*255);
    g = Math.floor((gg / (gg + Math.pow(1 - g, power)))*255);
    b = Math.floor((bb / (bb + Math.pow(1 - b, power)))*255);
    return {r,g,b};    
}
```

Using it

```
var dat = ctx.getPixelData(0,0,100,100);
var data = dat.data;
var i = 0;
while(i < data.length){
    var res = contrastPixel(data[i],data[i+1],data[i+2],power);
    data[i++] = res.r;
    data[i++] = res.g;
    data[i++] = res.b;
    i++;
}
ctx.putImageData(dat,0,0);
```

The argument power controls the contrast.

```
power = 1; // no change to the image
0 < power < 1; // reduces contrast
1 < power; // increases contrast
```

Because the scaling of power is logarithmic it can be hard to control with a linear slider. To give the slider a linear feel use the following instructions to get a value from a slider

For a slider with a min -100 and max 100 and center 0 (0 being no contrast change) get the contrast power value using

```
power = Math.pow(((Number(slider.value)* 0.0498) + 5)/5,Math.log2(10));
```

It's not perfectly linear, and the range is limited but will cover most needs.

The test image shows the results. Center bottom is the original. Using the scale in the paragraph above from left to right slider values of -100, -50, 50, 100

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [specification for the filter effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1) by the W3C.

It gives [an equivalent](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#contrastEquivalent) for the CSS contrast filter using SVG filters. It also gives [the maths](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#attr-valuedef-type-linear) behind the SVG filter.

To sum, for each channel (R, G, and B), this filter does:

```js
channel = channel * contrast - 0.5 * contrast + 0.5
```